# Run window message 'Identical line'

Tags: dart, flutter

Should I be concerned about the following message in the Run window? :

```
I/chatty  ( 7764): uid=10079(com.homemy.myapp) Thread-67 identical 24 lines
```

Comment: What is the line before that line?

Comment: The full text in Run window is : Performing full restart...
    Restarted app in 1,798ms.
    I/flutter ( 7764): myDate.day is 16
    I/flutter ( 7764): myDate.day is 16
I/chatty  ( 7764): uid=10079(com.homemy.myspriteapp) Thread-78 
    identical 17 lines, 
    I/flutter ( 7764): myDate.day is 16
    I/flutter ( 7764): myDate.day is 16 The 'identical 17 lines' varies.

Comment: If I take the print statement out it doesn't appear. The print statement is only added as a test. I am concerned if the app is doing unnecessary work.

Comment: You sould use `debugPrint` instead https://flutter.io/debugging/#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs. That should become a NoOp in release mode.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what is NoOp ?

Comment: @rozerro https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
I/flutter ( 7764): myDate.day is 16
I/chatty ( 7764): uid=10079(com.homemy.myspriteapp) Thread-78 identical 17 lines
```

Presumably your code that prints `myDate.day is 16` has run multiple times in a short space of time so rather than fill the output up, it's been folded into that message.

Whether this is bad depends where the code is; if it's somewhere that is expected to run many times (like inside a loop) then of course it's fine. If it's somewhere you would not expect to execute multiple times, you may be able to understand why it is by adding a breakpoint and reviewing the call stack.

Answer (score 4):

After two hours of debugging I can tell you not to underestimate that message. In my case, printing a dynamic value in a cycle, I got that message. I only found out after that I had a looping cycle. In fact, when I debugged the first cycle where I printed a string, there was an anomaly, that is, it stopped randomly without reason. This made me understand that it was the instructions already executed that created this anomaly even before I passed from the cause (loop of second cycle).