# I/chatty - identical 1 line in console output

Tags: flutter, dart

When I debugging the app I get in console lines like this, - what does it mean?

> I/chatty  (22231): uid=10141(com.githubname.appid) Thread-2 identical
> 1 line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run window message 'Identical line'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366904/run-window-message-identical-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Debugging when there are any repeated things which means the same. So the debug console would not print the line every time it will just tell the they are identical as above.